# Split multi line delimiter

Tags: java, arrays, class, oop, arraylist

Trying to split a text file which contains information about an album that has different formatting. Each album is divided by the dashed line with the first line of each section containing information about the album which is separated by colons and the lines after are the tracks in the album.

```
1:Whatever People Say I Am That's What I'm Not:Arctic Monkeys:2006:1.95M
The View from the Afternoon (3:38)
I Bet You Look Good on the Dancefloor (2:53)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2:Different Class:Pulp:1996:1.33M
Mis-Shapes (3:46)
Pencil Skirt (3:11)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
20:Konnichiwa:Skepta:2016:207K
Konnichiwa (3:16)
Lyrics (2:36)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I need help to split this into an album object. I've made the album class :

```
    //Album attributes
    private String salesRanking;
    private String title;
    private String artistName;
    private String yearRelease;
    private String sales;
    private String [] tracks; //Array of string to store each track in album

    //Album object constructor
    public Album (String salesRanking, String title, String artistName, String yearRelease, String sales, String [] tracks){
        this.salesRanking = salesRanking;
        this.title = title;
        this.artistName = artistName;
        this.yearRelease = yearRelease;
        this.sales = sales;
        this.tracks = tracks;
    }
```

To split the text file and put the content into the album object is where I'm having issues. I've tried

```
    //Store album objects
    ArrayList <String []> bulkAlbum = new ArrayList<>();


        try{
            //Read file
            FileReader freader = new FileReader(albumData);
            BufferedReader breader = new BufferedReader(freader);
            
            String line;
            
            while((line=breader.readLine()) != null ){
                //Removes empty array
                if(line.startsWith("-")){
                    continue;
                }

                //Split each album entry
                String [] albumDetail = line.split("-");
                bulkAlbum.add(albumDetail);
                line = "";

            }
            breader.close();
            freader.close();
        
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
```

When I run the code the output shows each line as an array of it's own in the arrayList, I realise the mistake I made is because it's only reading line by line but I don't know where to go from here so that the text file is read whole then split or split as chunks by the dashed line to create the album object.

Concatenating the lines then using ":" to split wont work because of the colon in the time.
I've been thinking about the logic but don't know what else to try.

---

EDIT - Finally solved this with the help of : [How to split text file into objects java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66830727/how-to-split-text-file-into-objects-java)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

Implementing the logic part of it assuming you'll take care of parsing and reading file.

```
    static class Block {
        String firstLine;
        List<String> tracks;

        public Block(String firstLine, List<String> tracks) {
            this.firstLine = firstLine;
            this.tracks = tracks;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Block> blocks = new ArrayList<>();
        try{
            //Read file
            FileReader freader = new FileReader("../");
            BufferedReader breader = new BufferedReader(freader);
            List<String> lines = (List<String>) breader.lines();
            int i = 0;
            while(i < lines.size()){
                List<String> addLines = new ArrayList<>();
                if(lines.get(i).startsWith("-")){
                    i++;
                } else {
                    while(!lines.get(i).startsWith("-")){
                        addLines.add(lines.get(i));
                        i++;
                    }
                    String firstLine = addLines.get(0);
                    addLines.remove(0);
                    Block block = new Block(firstLine,addLines);
                    blocks.add(block);
                }
            }
            breader.close();
            freader.close();

        } catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }

        List<Album> albums = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Block block: blocks) {
            //Implement these Methods by yourself
            parseFirstLine(block.firstLine);
            parseListOfTracks(block.tracks);
        }

    }
```